# Rmarkdown ioslides turn off fade-in behavior on .build

Tags: r-markdown, ioslides

When I knit my `.Rmd` files to `ioslides`, the incrementally built bullets fade-in painfully slowly.  The main title does the same thing.  Can I turn off this "fade-in" behavior somehow (everywhere if possible, and at least on my .build bullets)?

Comment: note that `transition: 0` only seems to apply to between-slide behavior, and doesn't affect the incrementally built bullets.